# Decrypting portions of AES encrypted file

Tags: c++, crypto++

For my C++ application, I have looked at Crypto++. Seems simple enough to encrypt some content and save it in a file. It also seems simple enough to decrypt the whole file. However, our requirement is that we cannot decrypt the whole file at once. I need to decrypt portions of the file on the fly as requested by the caller. Essentially, I need to implement the following pseudo methods:

```
  int openFile(const char* aesFile); // returns a handle
  long read(int handle, long pos, int size, byte* buffer);
```

How can I achieve this? Is there something in Crypto++ or some other library that is readily available to do this? Regards.

Comment: What mode of operation is the file encrypted with? Only some modes support random access, with others you'll need to decrypt from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I achieve this? Is there something in Crypto++ ...

I think you need two things. First, you need a ***seekable*** cipher mode of operation. [Counter mode (CTR)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CTR_Mode) will probably work for that. You can check if a cipher is seekable using [IsRandomAccess()](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_stream_transformation.html#a3aa2d47acbd55ed7e82a0519497f1cf7). Its inherited from [StreamTransfoormation Class](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_stream_transformation.html).

In counter mode (and other seekable modes), be careful to ensure you still have authenticity assurances. This can be tricky. Also see [Authenticated Encryption](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) on the [Crypto++ wiki](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/).

Second, probably you need to ***avoid*** the streaming interface, and you need to use ***`Put`*** and ***`Get`***. ***`Put`*** and ***`Get`*** are just C-like class functions present on every Crypto++ ***`BufferedTransformation`*** class.

Most examples of ***`Put`*** and ***`Get`*** are rather trivial. However, a more substantial one recently made an appearance on the [Crypto++ wiki](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/) at [Init-Update-Final](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Init-Update-Final). Though its more substantial, its not more complex because its a simple concept.

---

> ... or some other library that is readily available to do this?

Well, that's a choice you have to make. If C++ and security libraries are your only library requirements, then you can also check out [Jack Lloyd's Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/).